# selectAll works only once in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, selection

I am going mad on this one...
On first call, refreshGraph() works perfectly : my graph is displayed.
On following calls, nothing happens. selectAll() returns an array of arrays as expected, *but my graph does not change*.
BUT... If I use select() instead of selectAll(), it works !
AND WORST... If I add join.select(".bar") before the join.selectAll(".bar") it works also !

Anyone could explain me why ?

I do not understand this behavior. I perfectly understand what select() and selectAll() are expected to return. Calling style() on both returned subselections should give the same results since data are the same, even if organized by group with selectAll, and flat with select. Am I right ?

```
var srcData = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 42]).range([0, 420]);

function refreshGraph() {

    join = d3.select(".chart").selectAll(".container").data(srcData);

    join.enter()
    .append("span").attr("class","container")
    .append("div").attr("class","bar");

    join
    .selectAll(".bar") // wont work, but will if select() instead of selectAll()
    .style("width", function(d) { 
        return x(d) + "px";
    });
}

function doChange() {
    for (var i = 0; i < srcData.length; i++) {
        srcData[i] /= 2;
    }
    refreshGraph();
}

refreshGraph();
```

Answer (score 6):

After hours and hours of reading the doc, and stepping into the D3 code, I finally get it. I combined several cases, which led me to stack of confusions.
So, what is this about ?

```
 join = d3.select(".chart").selectAll(".container").data(srcData);
 join.enter()
.append("span").attr("class","container")
.append("div").attr("class","bar");
```

The [append()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-append) function does something tricky to help you :

*Appends a new element with the specified name as the last child of each element in the current selection, returning a new selection containing the appended elements. **Each new element inherits the data of the current elements**, if any, in the same manner as select for subselections.*

BUT... The *inherit* word is misleading. You have to read : *Each new element receives **a copy** of the data from current elements*

As the way D3 works, there is no magic binding. The same way you re-bind data each time you want to reflect the change of values, you have to set the data in the correct nodes. The append() function did the job for you, the select() function can do it as well, but the [selectAll()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-selectAll) DOES NOT.

*For each element in the current selection, selects descendant elements that match the specified selector string. ... **The subselection does not inherit data from the current selection;***

In my question code, at the first call, the data is copied from .container to .bar elements by append(). As the data do not change in quantity (no new/ no less values), the subsequent calls bypass the append() function (enter() section is empty) and selectAll() will get the correct nodes (.bar classed) which still have the previous data version. When style() is called, this not the new data that are applied.

And of course, using select() make it works since it copy the data from the ancestor to the subselection element.

nrabinowitz gave a correct anwser : if you absolutly want to use selectAll, you have to use a function to retrieve the data for grouped nodes.

selectAll() doc says : *The returned selection **is grouped by the ancestor node** in the current selection ... if the data value is specified as a function, this function will be called with the data d of the ancestor node and the group index i to determine the data bindings for the subselection.*

Hope it will help...

Answer (score 5):

The issue here is when the data is bound for sub-elements.

- The initial data for the `.container` elements is bound when you call `.selectAll('.container').data(srcData)`, and *re-bound* with new data each time you call it again.
- The data for the `.bar` elements is bound on creation, when they're appended to the `.container` elements, but *not* rebound when you bind new data to `.container`.

The fix is to forcibly rebind the `.bar` data to its parent each time you call `refreshData`:

```
join
    .selectAll(".bar")
    .data(function(d) { return [d]; })
    .style("width", function(d) { 
        return x(d) + "px";
    });
```

Comment: But my refreshGraph() starts with d3.select(".chart").selectAll(".container").data(srcData). Meaning the data are bound to .container elements each time the function is called. Then the missing nodes are added by the join.enter() BUT the style is not applied yet.  It should be set by the join.selectAll(".bars")... which means "get all the .bar classed elements from the .container (join selection) and apply this style". Also, it will work with select() ! Why ?

Comment: .select() binds the parent data to the child. But it's only a single-element selection, so it's not going to work in this case.